# Left car battery "tipped" for a few months--is it safe to use?

Tags: battery, leak, battery-testing

A few months ago, I bought a new car battery and stored it sideways (silly me!) There's been a fair amount of leakage, which I've cleaned up. Is the car battery safe to use in a car? Is there some way for me to tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need to top up the liquid level to above the plates.

I suggest that you check the ph of the existing liquid so it can be matched.

A good battery shop can mix the acid / water to that level - so can you if you have the acid of sufficient strength.